# Innovations vector in MA Time Series Model

Tags: r, time-series

I am using `auto.arima` function( in `forecast` R package) to fit MA model (like $X_t=Z_t+Z_{t-1}$). How can get vector of $Z_t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fit <- auto.arima(x)
z <- residuals(fit)
```